# Laravel 5 CRUD application not functioning as i want

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, crud

I'm new to the Laravel but I have to create fill in the blanks in paragraph through Create form. All I need is when I press submit button on create form those parameters should fill this index.blade.php's paragraph's blanks.see this.

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
    @foreach($items as $item)
        <tr>
            <p>
                This is to hereby certify that, pursuant to ..... the Contract between ..... under the said
                contract,including all but not least, for ...... main and miscellaneous eqipment ..... have successfully
                supplied on dd/mm/yy
            </p>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
@endsection
```

Here is the index.blade.php which i created

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

    @foreach($items as $item)
        <tr>

            <p>
                This is to hereby certify that, pursuant to
                <td>{{ $item->po }}</td>
                the Contract between
                <td>{{ $item->company }}</td>
                under the said contract,including all but not least, for
                <td>{{ $item->boq_name }}</td>
                main and miscellaneous eqipment for
                <td>{{ $item->project_name }}</td>
                have successfully supplied on dd/mm/yy
            </p>

        </tr>
    @endforeach
@endsection
```

if i create new parameters through create function then submit index view file repeated that paragraph with filled blanks.but i want is when i press submit keep the paragraph same but need to change parameters only.can anyone suggest what should go here.

here is my controller functions

```
public function index()
{
    $items = SummeryForm::all();

    return view('summeryform/index', compact('items'));
}


public function create()
{
    return view('summeryform/create');
}


public function store(Request $request)
{
    $item = new SummeryForm;
    // $item ->id = Auth::user() ->id;
    $item ->po = $request ->po; 
    $item ->company = $request ->company;
    $item ->boq_name = $request ->boq_name;
    $item ->project_name = $request ->project_name;
    $item ->save();

    SummeryForm::create($request->all());

    return redirect()->route('summeryform.index')
                    ->with('success','Item created successfully');
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: You probably want to consider narrowing this question down to be more focused and include just a small isolated test-case piece of the code; it's really hard to tell what you're asking here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not very clear about your question, as I understand that you want only one paragraph to appear with the last **item** after click submit button.

If I understand right, you just need to change your index method to

```
public function index()
{
    $item = SummeryForm::all()->last();
    return view('summeryform/index', compact('item'));
}
```

and index.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
     <tr>
         <p>This is to hereby certify that, pursuant to <td>{{ $item->po }}</td>  the Contract  between <td>{{ $item->company }}</td> under the said contract,including all but not least, for <td>{{ $item->boq_name }}</td> main and miscellaneous eqipment for <td>{{ $item->project_name }}</td> have successfully supplied on dd/mm/yy</p>
    </tr>
@endsection
```

Comment: you are correct sir.but it gives this error ...Undefined variable: items (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\demo\resources\views\summeryform\index.blade.php)